# Is there anything in ASP.Net like applet in java

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of a Java applet in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301129/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-java-applet-in-net)

Hi,

Is there anything in ASP.Net3.5 like applet in java

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) would be the closest match. Although is not "ASP" but ".net"

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two different technologies. ASP .NET is a server technology (which renders HTML code understood by browsers), while Java applets are chunks of code downloaded right off the web server and executed in a sandboxed environment inside the browser, hence this is a client-side technology.

To answer your question, the closest match to a java applet would be an ActiveX control (with the inherent drawbacks - works only in IE under Windows, requires some privileges, etc.). Although not from the same dough, [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net) would be what you are really looking for and seems very promising in terms of user experience (far better than Flash - but this is a biased assertion).

Silverlight apps are easy to program once you have a C# / ASP .NET background and in addition to Visual Studio, Expression Blend makes a great companion to create, edit and animate stuff for Silverlight.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Javaapplet is clientside so you could still write your applets in java. For rich client side programming you may consider silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is, [XBAP](http://www.xbap.org/)! You should check it out, it's WPF though. Or [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/), but XBAP is a little bit more like Applets since it's downloaded and runned in a jail on the client.